# Prove that $a, b, c$ are in arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Question: If $a(\frac1b+\frac1c), b(\frac1a+\frac1c),$ and $c(\frac1b+\frac1a)$ are in Arithmetic Progression, then prove that $a, b, c$ are in Arithmetic Progression.

My attempt:-
Let $a, b, c$ be in Arithmetic Progression. 
$$2b = a + c$$
$$(a + c)/b = 2$$
$$(2b - a)/c = 1$$
$$(2b - c)/a = 1$$

$$(a + c)/b = (2b - a)/c + (2b - c)/a$$
$$(a/b) + (c/b) = (2b/c) - (a/c) + (2b/a) - (c/a)$$

$$a((1/b)+(1/c)) + c((1/b)+(1/a)) = 2b((1/a)+(1/c))$$
Therefore, $a(\frac1b+\frac1c), b(\frac1a+\frac1c),$ and $c(\frac1b+\frac1a)$ are in Arithmetic Progression. Which was given, so we can say that $a, b, c$ are in Arithmetic Progression.

I just want to know if my solution is correct or not. If not then please provide correct solution.

Comment: It cannot be correct: you are proving the converse. Present a new attempt.

Comment: This argument is not simply reversible, since you cannot directly infer  your second through fourth lines from your fifth.  To start at your last line to prove the _given_ proposition, you'll need to manipulate the ratios differently to show that the equation _can_ be reduced to $  \ 2b \ = \ a + c \ $ without assigning numerical values to any expressions.

Comment: Another approach: Add $1$ to each term and note you can divide by $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$

Comment: @HariShankar But you might not be able to.

Comment: @CalvinLin you are right, that caveat needs to be included. thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

As $b\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a\right)-a\left(\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c\right)=c\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b\right)-b\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a\right)$

$\iff b\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a\right)+1-\left(a\left(\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c\right)+1\right)=c\left(\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b\right)+1-\left(b\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a\right)+1\right)$

But $b\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a\right)+1=b\underbrace{\left(\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b\right)}$ assuming $b,\dfrac1b\ne0$

If $\dfrac1c+\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b\ne0,$ cancelling it from both sides to find  $$b-a=c-b$$

Comment: In particular, the original claim is not true, eg for $ a = 1, b = -2, c = -2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, which  claim is referred to here ?

Comment: OP's problem that if those 3 expressions are in AP, then $a, b, c$ are in AP. (Unless AP was defined to have a non-zero difference.) $\quad$ IE when$ 1/a+1/b+1/c = 0$, then those 3 expressions all all equal 1 (hence in AP), but clearly we can find non-AP $a, b, c$ like $1, -2, -2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I believe they have tacitly assumed $$\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c\ne0$$

Comment: Agreed, like with positive reals/integers. It's still worthwhile to point out that the current claim isn't true.

Comment: @CalvinLin, No doubt. Thanks for pointing out.